What does "do it double" mean?
What does "do it double" mean? For example,  10:20 in https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mLvpAcuNfxs&t=10m

I’m voting to close this question because it makes us click on a video link that does not work.

The link worked for me. Presumably he means 'do it in two ways at once'. It's not a usual expression in English.

@KateBunting - It seems YouTube decided to deny me the video because I am using an ad blocker (it does this occasionally).

It refers back to "the two types of resonance".  I'm voting to close. There's no special use of English here, the words just have regular meaning.  The only way to understand is to watch the video, in which he explains "creating resonance above the pen and below the pen".  YMMV

Please edit the question to put in it a transcription of the sentence you are asking about and the surrounding few sentences for context. The question will then be reopened.

@DJClayworth While I agree that it should include a transcript, it will still be difficult to understand without the instructor's audio example.
